# Move a div class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, move

I'm working on a one page website, I've made a [three sliders and menu to activate each slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebsiO.jpg) (the first slider is active by default)

I've used a javascript method to move a class `.is-active` to another html element for display it. But nothing work. can you help me ?

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('.menu a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.slider.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      $('.slider:eq('+$(this).data('index')+')').addClass('is-active');
      $('.c-tabs-nav__link.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      $('#bt-category-actu .c-tabs-nav__link:eq('+$(this).data('index')+')').addClass('is-active');
 });
```

});

Thank you

Comment: You could see the error message checking the console of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the index of 'menu a' (anchor tag) and make .slider of same index active, then try

```
$(this).index()
```

instead of

```
$(this).data('index')
```

because $(this).data('index') will return 'undefined'

Comment: This solution also don't work, thank you for your help. ... I've found the solution, i've forgot to add data-index to my menu ...